# Eclipse Neon cannot start a java debug session

Tags: eclipse, debugging, nullpointerexception, eclipse-neon

I'm using Eclipse Neon from the release date. Yesterday I got some strange errors in Eclipse and after a reboot of the Eclipse instance everything was gone. I installed Eclipse and my plugins again. Everything is working again but when I launch the Java debugger on one of my project I got the error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "XXXX".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This error occurs on debugging all my projects also in another workspace. Can someone help me with this? The error is not explaining what the exact problem is.

In the logfile of Eclipse I can found the follow error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdi.Bootstrap.virtualMachineManager(Bootstrap.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.StandardVMDebugger.getConnector(StandardVMDebugger.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.StandardVMDebugger.run(StandardVMDebugger.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.pde.launching.AbstractPDELaunchConfiguration.launch(AbstractPDELaunchConfiguration.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory for a more detailed message.

Comment: Tnx addd more detailed error message to the question.

Comment: Looks like something fundamental is still wrong with your Eclipse. Maybe try starting Eclipse with the -clean option.

Comment: Just started Eclipse with the -clean argument. Nothing has changed.
I think it's better to do a clean install of my Eclipse Enviroment. Just tested debugging in a just download Eclipse and thats working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fully removed my previous Eclipse environment. Settings included.
Installed Eclipse environment from a clean install and installed all my plugins again. The problem was fixed.